# How can I get IronPython in C# to run a script that requires an active VENV? Is this possible?

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I've installed IronPython 3.4 (https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/releases/tag/v3.4.1) and I'm trying to run several font-related python scripts that depend upon an active VENV (FontTools, ftCLI, and some other packages).

Is this even possible? I have been doing some research on IronPython, but nothing mentions virtual environments.

Is it possible to accomplish what I need? Is there another solution that will run a script in an active VENV using C#?

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, you need to pass the full path to the `venv` version of Python.

A `venv` consists of:

- A directory e.g. `/home/bob/dev/project/.venv` or `C:/Users/Bob/dev/project/.venv` which contains the the things which constitute the `venv`.

  - a local repository where python modules are installed
  - a directory of scripts, which are stubs for launching Python, Pip, etc. (e.g. `bin` for Linux)
  - a script called `activate` which modifies the environment of the current shell so that those scripts are called first, and so that Python will look in `site-packages` first.

If called from a shell, such as Bash, Zsh, Powershell or Cmd, the `activate` script will modify the environment of the shell, so that when you type `python`, the version of python is the `venv` python. You "activate" the venv with either `call .venv/Scripts/activate.cmd` for windows, or `source .venv/bin/activate` for Linux.

However if you just want to ensure that the python module or file is run in the `venv`, all you have to do is specify the full path the `venv` python stub.

E.g. on Windows:

```cs
var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(
    @"C:\Users\Bob\dev\project\.venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
  ){
    ArgumentList = {
      "-m",
      "@C:\Users\Bob\dev\project\main_module.py" // add other arguments as needed
    }
}
proc = Process.Start(psi);
```

So how does this work?

The `.exe` files in `.venv\Scripts` (Windows) or `.venv/bin` (Linux) are small executables which check their own names and directory to discover the correct venv location, and python version. They then launch the real Python, Pip etc, with the correct environment.

The situation on Linux etc is very similar, except that the directories are named differently, e.g. `.venv/bin` instead of `.venv/scripts`.